# How can I diff two files against each other from within Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, diff

In Visual Studio 2010, is there a built-in way, or a free add-on that can open a file comparison for two selected files?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to select two files in the Solution Explorer, right click on one of them, and be presented an option to compare the two files (in a side-by-side diffing tool).

I'm aware of [Visual Studio Comparison Tools](http://comparisontools.codeplex.com/), but my understanding is that it does not work under Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro like this to call a diff program of your choice:

```
Sub DiffTwoSelectedFilesOrCrash()
    DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()

    Dim items As SelectedItems = DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).DTE.SelectedItems
    If items.Count = 2 Then
        Dim path1 As String = items.Item(1).Collection.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileNames(1)
        Dim path2 As String = items.Item(1).Collection.Item(2).ProjectItem.FileNames(1)

        Dim diffProgram As String = "C:\Program Files\SourceGear\DiffMerge\DiffMerge.exe"
        Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        p.Start(diffProgram, path1 + " " + path2)

    End If
End Sub
```

You can then assign a keyboard shortcut to run the macro, via Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.

Comment: Perfect.  I wasn't sure if there was a way to add the macro to the right-click menu, but I was easily able to assign a keyboard hotkey to run the Macro.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Devarts Code Compare? There is a free version [here](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/download.html). The free version does have some limitations but it may include everything that you need ([also see the feature matrix](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/featurematrix.html)). See the site for more info.

You can look at code blocks or files side by side and see the differences (see below) .
[image]

It will also let you synchronize the differences using the >> buttons shown in the image.

Comment: Thanks.  That works somewhat, though it doesn't allow me to diff two selected files - I have to open a comparison with the tool, and browse to each of my files individually.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that you just want to click on the file to make your selections without having to browse for them?

Comment: Right.  I can always use an external diff program to browse to two different files and diff them, but the reason I want Visual Studio integration is so I don't have to browse - I want to just select two files in the Solution Explorer and hit diff.

Comment: Gotcha. Just in case you didn't notice, though, it does integrate into Visual Studio for you. However you do have to browse for the files to select them, which can be done by going to Tools > Code Compare and then selecting the solution files using the elipses at the top of the side by side windows. The screen shot above was from within VS. I just cropped the image to keep the file size small. Please post back if you do happen to find a solution.